# when i click a button second time my label want to dissappear

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

i have a button and label like this:

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<label  id="lbl">lbl</label>
```

When i click this button second time that label want to hide/dissappear

Comment: no , if i click a button 2 times the label my to hide

Comment: I have added the solution, when you want an event to fire on double click, use **ondblclick** even from JS

Comment: Hi, did you want it to disappear on a double click or on a second click (they aren't the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code :

```js
button = document.getElementById("btn")
label = document.getElementById("lbl")

button.addEventListener('dblclick', function(){
  label.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<label  id="lbl">lbl</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onclick event of the button. Add JQuery and use the below code.

```
var cnt = 0;
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  cnt++;
  if(cnt == 2)
    $('#lbl').hide();
})
```

OR, in vanilla js you can use

```
var cnt = 0;
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  cnt++;
  if(cnt == 2)
    document.getElementById('lbl').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand why they need to start to learn jquery to do this simple thing.

Comment: @AHaworth added vanilla javascript code as well.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

Use Inbuilt JS event

There is event in JS **ondblclick** event which fires only on double clicked
check the snippet below

```js
function hide() {
  document.querySelector("label").style.display= "none";
}
```

```html
<button  ondblclick="hide()" id="btn">Button</button>
<label  id="lbl">Hide me after Double clicking on button</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
let count = 0
const btn =   document.getElementById("btn");
   btn.onclick = function () {
            count++;
       if(count === 2){
        document.querySelector("label").style.display= "none";
       }
        }
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<label  id="lbl">lbl</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided not hide or dissappear

There is a chance of your'e code is being overwrited by other css.

Answer (score 0):

It's divided to 3 steps:

1. Set the counter to count the clicks.
2. Add the click listener on button and increment the counter by 1 on click.
3. If the counter reaches 2, modify the CSS of label with `display: none` to make it disappear

Here's the pure Javascript solution:

```js
var lbl = document.getElementById('lbl');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var clicks = 0;

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  clicks++;
  if (clicks === 2) lbl.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<label  id="lbl">lbl</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a count of the number of times the button has been clicked and when it reaches 2 make the lbl display none.

This snippet adds an event listener to the label to achieve this.

```js
let count = 0;
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const lbl = document.querySelector('#lbl');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  count++;
  if (count == 2) {
    lbl.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Button</button>
<label id="lbl">lbl</label>
```